# dynamic sql and how to escape special characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which searches for names based on a string.

if I pass in `@SearchTerm` as the following value: `o'clock`

```
SET @NameSearch = ' (CONTAINS(lmc.Name,''"*' + REPLACE(@SearchTerm,'''','''''') + '*"'')) '
```

`@NameSearch` would be set to:

```
"*o''clock*"
```

this would return no rows.

however if I just pass in `'clock'` then I will get all the results which have a name that contains the word `'clock'`.

could someone explain to me how I would be able to escape the `'` properly.

Comment: What happens if you just replace the single quote with an empty string? I'm not sure that Full-Text Search cares about apostrophes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use parametrized query. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @paramlist nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql= 'SELECT Test_Name
              FROM [Test]
              WHERE (1 = 1)'

SELECT @sql = @sql + ' AND (Test_Name LIKE (@Name + ''Toto''))'

SELECT @paramlist = '@Name nvarchar (256)'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @paramlist, @SearchTerm
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that when you do this in addition to not having to escape the strings you get the benefit of not having to worry about SQLi attacks

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You wrote 
   *if @NameSearch would be set to: "*o''clock*"* , but I guess you mean @SearchTerm

**2.**
What is the result of

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"*o''clock*" ', 1033, 0, 0)
```

One, two or three rows? May be you have  problems with wordbreakers.  Setup your language first, possibly it is not English (1033).

**3.**
If I would need to run it dynamically, then I would double apostrophes once more:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)= 'SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (''"*o''''clock*" '', 1033, 0, 0)'
exec(@sql)
```

That is ok, but since you are going to automatically double apostrophes, then you could put extra apostrophes just by error.. Possibly you should dig this direction or present us clear code snippet.